# PHP: regex replace weird result

Tags: php, regex

I have a list of badwords one of them is "S.A."
All my words are saved in an array and I loop through the array and do the replacement.
The word S.A. replaces things which I don't want replaced, i need it only to replace S.A. as a word itself.
So example "This S.A. was bad." should become "This was bad".
But now when I run it on a string with (for example) SEAS in it, it will replace it... no idea why...

ps: the if then check is because if the string $v is exactly the badword, it should not be removed.
Shouldn't the \b word indicator in the regex make the word an exact match?

ps: I only want to remove full words, not a part of a word.
If I have Apple in the badlist but someone wrote Apples it should not be replaced.

```
foreach ($this->badwordArr as $badword) {
    if (strtoupper($v) == strtoupper($badword)) {

        // no replace because its the only word
        $data[$key] = $v;

    } else {

        $pattern = "/\b$badword\b/i";
        $v = preg_replace($pattern, " ", $v);
    }       
}
```

What's wrong with my regex pattern?!?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dot is a meta character in a regex that represents any character. You need to escape it:

```
S\.A\.
```

To avoid revising your whole list, you can use:

```
$badword_escaped = preg_quote($badword);
$pattern = "/\b$badword_escaped\b/i";
```

Comment: I thought it would be something like this. Thank you for the quick solution.